# Javascript How can I toggle video fullscreen without clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to toggle an html video fullscreen from a mobile app.

Basically, when I press a button, it should send data to the database via web service. Depending on the data given, the video should toggle between fullscreen and not fullscreen.

Now my problem is that, html video doesn't allow this one because for security reason as it says in the error. I have tried simulating a button click using `trigger()` but it still says the same error wherein it is not allowed because of security reasons.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
  launchFullScreen(document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]);
})
var count = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  console.log(count);
  if(count == 5) {
    $("button").click();
  }
}, 1000);

// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> 
<input type="text" id="test">
<button>Fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: Read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-html5-20090423/video.html#video), it's not allowed. `User agents should not provide a public API to cause videos to be shown full-screen.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get html 5 video to automatically open in fullscreen mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20257355/get-html-5-video-to-automatically-open-in-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: Why not just call the `launchFullScreen` function instead of simulating a click (`$("button").click();`) ....